# A smart way of proving that $\langle A/\mathfrak{a}, +, . \rangle$ is a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

Here is the proposition I have:

Let $f: A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism, then $\operatorname{ker}f$ is an ideal of $A,$ and $\operatorname{Im}f$ is a subring of $B.$ And we have $A/\operatorname{ker}f  \cong \operatorname{Im}f.$

And here are the definitions of the operations $+$ and $.$ in $ \langle A/\mathfrak{a}, +, . \rangle :$

If $x \in A,$ then the cosets of $A/\mathfrak{a}$ are of the form $ x + \mathfrak{a}.$ Now, define, $$ (x + \mathfrak{a}) + (y + \mathfrak{a}) = (x + y) + \mathfrak{a}$$ And $$ (x + \mathfrak{a})(y + \mathfrak{a}) = xy + \mathfrak{a}.$$ Now, I want to prove that $ \langle A/\mathfrak{a}, + \rangle$ is an abelian group in a smart way,

1- Can I say that it is an abelian group by the first Isomorphism theorem for groups? also,

2- Is the ordinary way of proving it is just by showing closure and associativity of $+$  and the existence of identity and inverse for every element in $A/\mathfrak{a}$?

Could anyone help me in answering those questions please?

Comment: If $G$ is an abelian group, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $G/H = \{g+H:g \in G\}$ is also an abelian group.

Comment: @azif00 Can you please mention the theorem that says this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the first isomorphism theorem for rings?   And the fact that $(A/\mathfrak a,+)$ is the abelian group of the quotient ring $(A/\mathfrak a,+,\cdot) $?

The answer to $2)$ is clearly yes.  That's I guess what I should say is any way of doing is going to be equivalent to that.

Comment: I do not see how I can use the first Isomorphism thm for rings? and how is this different from using the first isomorphism theorem for groups. Could you clarify the details please?

Comment: Well the one for rings is, to my memory,  completely analogous to the one for groups.   Here the kernel is an ideal,  and the image is a ring isomorphic to the quotient of the domain ring by that ideal.

Comment: Should not I show that the image is a ring to be able to use it?

Comment: And, part of the definition of a ring is that it is an abelian group.

Comment: No, the image is a ring by the theorem.

Comment: So you are saying basically in the proof of the abelian group part there is nothing to do other than saying by the first Iso morphism theorem for rings, the quotient with the addition operation is an abelian group, right?

Comment: How about the proof of the distributivity of multiplication over addition and the associativity of multiplication? Is there a smart way to prove this also?

Comment: You can always do it by hand;   but using the theorem you almost get it for free.